# Analysing syntax: What are the main clauses in these two Latin sentences from "Brevarium" by Eutropius?

Tags: syntax

everyone. Here are the sentences and my thoughts about them:

1: Is veniens eodem itinere, quo etiam Hannibal venerat a consulibus Ap. Claudio Nerone et M. Livio Salinatore apud Senam, Piceni civitatem, in insidias conpositas incidit.

I feel certain that "veniens eodem itinere, quo etiam Hannibal venerat" is not part of the main clause. But I`m not certain whether the adverbial "apud Senam" and the appositive "Piceni civitatem" is part of the main clause or not.

2: In Hispania a fratre eius Hasdrubale ambo Scipiones, qui per multos annos victores fuerant, interficiuntur, exercitus tamen integer mansit; casu enim magis erant quam virtute decepti.

I think that "In Hispania a fratre eius Hasdrubale ambo Scipiones + interficiuntur" is the main clause here. But I`m not completely sure.

What do you think?